# Increase the SetWindowsHookEx limit in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, keyboard-hook

It appears that Windows 7 (some say also Windows Vista) enforces a limit to the number of times a hook can be placed through `SetWindowsHookEx`.

I'm writing a Java application and using [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) to get the keyboard and mouse hooks to the system (in order to track their activity outside the application). The issue is, after about a 100 times of doing so, the procedure to get hooks simply stops working - **silently** (with no exception thrown).

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;

static void listenerInit() throws NativeHookException {

    GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    // add listeners

}
```

I tried to look for a solution to **increase this limit**, so that I don't need to keep restarting the computer so often just to reset the counter. All I got so far is a suggestion to [add a registry key](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/56093d14-c1bc-4d0a-a915-57fef0695191/windows-7-setwindowshookex-callback-proc-stops-getting-called-after-exceeding-max-time-allowed) to increase the timeout to 10 seconds, *but that doesn't sound right.*

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\
LowLevelHooksTimeout=10000
// why do this?
```

Apparently, [this is not ideal](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f6032ca1-31b8-4ad5-be39-f78dd29952da/hooking-problem-in-windows-7) for a developer as it's a user-oriented workaround for slow applications that use hooks. But I am only testing the application by terminating it and running it repeatedly. In a deployed environment, it would only run once at start up. **Will this work for my test system?**

**How can I increase this limit?** Also I don't understand the relation between the timeout value and the reason why more new hooks cannot be created after the limit is reached.

Please note that I'm only interested in either a Java-based solution, or a solution involving the modification of the test system OS configuration (Windows 7 Professional). I've seen some suggestions involving writing some C++ or C# libraries that I'm not interested in.

Also, will this be solved if I upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: FWIW I found that logging off and logging back on will reset the counter, although switching user doesn't seem to help (I only tried switching back to the same account, didn't try switching to a different account). Although still troublesome, log off/on is faster than a full restart.

Answer (score 1):

> It appears that Windows 7 (some say also Windows Vista) enforces a limit to the number of times a hook can be placed through SetWindowsHookEx.

That is correct, everything after Windows XP added **undocumented restrictions** to the SetWindowsHookEx API call presumably due to the number of applications abusing this call and delaying event delivery to other applications thus slowing the input response for user input.  Again, there is almost no documentation from Microsoft about when this occurs, how to detect it or even how to prevent the behavior from occurring.

> Apparently, this is not ideal for a developer... Will this work for my test system?

This is probably the stupidest API design decision I have personally ever seen.  I believe the `LowLevelHooksTimeout` registry key was intended to set how long the hook can block before the OS kill's it, however, I noticed **no difference** when changing this value and deliberately delaying hook execution.  In short, that registry key seems to do nothing.

> How can I increase this limit?

I don't believe there is any way to fix this behavior, although I have not been able to reproduce the issue.  If you can produce the problem reliably, please, please file a bug at https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/issues with example code that works without an IDE so I can reproduce the problem and test solutions.

**Further reading:**

https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/issues/detail?id=43
https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/issues/detail?id=48

Comment: Thanks. I will try to make a simple program that will attempt to exceed the hook limits as quickly as possible. But do note that your library (and perhaps the hook mechanism itself) doesn't throw any errors on a failed hook. It simply continues as though the hook attempt passed - just that the listener can no longer get any events.

Comment: Yes, that is because the underlying C code has no idea it stopped working.  As far as the program knows, the hook is installed, it just isn't getting any events.